# Harmonic conjugate

Tags: analysis, complex-analysis, functions

I have been asked the following question and would appreciate an explanation.

Suppose we have to find an analytic function $F(z)$ where $z=x+iy\in \mathbb C$ and its real part is $g(x,y)$. Question: Does it suffice to be given $F(z)=g(z,0)$ for us to  determine $F(z)$ in general?

I am not sure though I guess the fact that analytic functions only depend on $z$ might be relevant? (I might be wrong though!)

Thank you.

Comment: What is $g(z,0)$? From what you first wrote, it seems as if $g$ is meant to be a function of two *real* variables.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo : I think they changed the arguments of $g$. I do not fully understand that myself, hence I am asking... :) Maybe the new arguments are $(z,\bar{z})$? this is a wild guess though.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo :  On second thoughts my suggestion of change of variable doesnt make sense since if $\bar{z}=0$ then so is $z$. Unfortunately this is the question as presented and I am rather confused...

Comment: Maybe the problem is to find an analytic function $F(z)$ with real part $g(z)=g(x,y)$, with an other condition like $F(0)=g(0)$. However, you should rewrite it if you want an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they mean $F(x) = g(x,0)$, i.e. on the real axis, the analytic function is real, and its values are given there.  The answer is yes, by the uniqueness theorem for analytic functions: any two analytic functions on a domain $D$ that are equal on a set that has a limit point in $D$ are equal everywhere in $D$.

Comment: Thanks, Robert! May I ask what do you mean by "has a limit point in $D$"? Also, would you mind perhaps giving me a link to a proof of this theorem?

Comment: Point $p$ is a limit point (or accumulation point) of set $S$ if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there are infinitely many points of $S$ within distance $\varepsilon$ of $p$.

Comment: ... but this is a level of generality that you probably don't need at this point.  More simply: if $F_1$ and $F_2$ are two possible choices for $F$, then  since the derivatives at a point on the real axis can be computed using only the values on that axis, we find that $F_1$ and $F_2$ have the same Taylor series about any point on the real axis.